# Put form input in variable (Python, Flask)

Tags: python, forms, flask, request

I am trying to retrieve the form input and put it in my variable (test), this is what I tried:

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, request, url_for
import random

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["DEBUG"] = True

vraag = "Wat is een barkie?"
ans = ['€10', '€50', '€100', '€1000']

@app.route("/")
def Q1():
    random.shuffle(ans)
    return render_template('main_page.html', vraag=vraag, ans=ans)


@app.route("/1", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def A1():
    test = request.POST
    return render_template('check.html', test=test)
```

main_page.html:

```
<body>
<p>{{ vraag }}</p>
{% for item in ans%}
<form method="POST" action="{{ url_for('A1') }}">
    <input type="submit" name={{ item }} value={{ item }} />
</form>
{% endfor %}
</body>
```

What am I doing wrong here? As error code it gives 'Unhandled Exception'

Comment: To retrieve data from a form, I always do _name = request.form.get('name') or None_ then I can check if name exists or not. I don't know about request.POST which I have never used. but if the error is an 'Unhandled Exception' then maybe wrapping ur code in try except statements and printing out the exception might help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`request.POST` in `A1` is not correct. Additionally you should wrap `item` in quotes.

A1 should look like:

```
@app.route("/1", methods=["GET", "POST"])
def A1():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        return render_template('check.html', test=str(request.form))
    else:
        return "This page doesn't accept GET requests."
```

`request.form` is an [`ImmutableMultiDict`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/0.11/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.ImmutableMultiDict) object, so you can get exact arguments passed from the form. The above example is only to show you what got passed to the form.